# Can't solve this system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

Could anyone please help me solve the following system of equations?

```
Solve[
  {-54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z) (1 + y + z)^2 - 
   54 (1 + x + y) (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z)^2 + 
   6 (3 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 z)^2 - (-2 x + 2 y z) w == 0. 
   -54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z) - 
   54 (1 + x + y) (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z)^2 + 
   6 (3 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 z)^2 - (-2 y + 2 x z) w == 0, 
   -54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z) - 
   54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z) (1 + y + z)^2 + 
   6 (3 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 z)^2 - (2 x y - 2 z) w == 0, 
   1 - x^2 - y^2 + 2 x y z - z^2 == 0}, 
  {x, y, z, w}]
```

Comment: If you put comma instead of the point after the first equation, your code solves the system. It has 34 solutions. The list is very long.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thank you for your comment. Okay, but what does this solution exactly mean, {z -> Root[{ 191 + 932 # + 1550 #^2 + 1161 #^3 + 405 #^4 + 54 #^5& , \ (-38226452847977561341017621894618382500058478927486278857781879586548\ 0731061839744267853563295101217162930421760) #\ + 3822645284797756134101762189461838250005847892748627885778187958654\ 80731061839744267853563295101217162930421760 #2& }, {3, 1}] ？Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Root. There you find an exhaustive answer to your question. Have in mind to apply the function `ToRadicals` to the `Root` object. If this is at all possible, it expresses the `Root` object in terms of radicals.

Answer (score 1):

If you `Rationalize` your equations ( or change `0.` to `0`) `Solve` gives a solution:

```
Solve[{-54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z) (1 + y + z)^2 - 54 (1 + x + y) (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z)^2 + 6 (3 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 z)^2 - (-2 x + 2 y z) w ==  0. - 54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z) - 54 (1 + x + y) (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z)^2 + 6 (3 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 z)^2 - (-2 y + 2 x z) w == 0, 
-54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z)^2 (1 + y + z) - 54 (1 + x + y)^2 (1 + x + z) (1 + y + z)^2 + 6 (3 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 z)^2 - (2 x y - 2 z) w == 0, 
1 - x^2 - y^2 + 2 x y z - z^2 == 0}//Rationalize, {x, y, z, w}]
(*{{x -> -(1/2), y -> -(1/2), z -> -(1/2), w -> 0},...}*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what does this in the first solution exactly mean, y -> Root[{
191 + 932 # + 1550 #^2 + 1161 #^3 + 405 #^4 + 54 #^5& , \
-954793986196202981448878875672784828867896342035077 - 211362948405958\
10499014725984381274016283788755497696 ...?Thanks.

Comment: Try `Normal[…]` or `N[…]` to get the values of the solution!